# is there a binary operator in beanshell for NOT

Tags: binary, operator-keyword, beanshell

Is there a binary operator in Beanshell for a logical negation `¬` (not) or a workaroung for it?
e.g.

```
 3∧¬5 = 2
```

Comment: can any language exist without 'NOT'? seems like a job for google.

Comment: I've tried 3&!5 but that gives me an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine bits exclusive to the two values (not on in both). Then mask off the first value to leave the bits that are exclusive in the second value, thus showing the bits that are not in the first value.

```
    a = 3;
    b = 5;
    print((a ^ b) & a); // ==>2
```